# Firebase App Distribution Task with Missing app id Error

Tags: android, kotlin, gitlab, gitlab-ci, firebase-app-distribution

I found an error when i setup firebase App disrtibution Gradle plugin.
(i add the token in the variable of gitlab and my OS)

The project environment is setup with gitlab CI/CD.

In this scenarios, we will encounter the Missing App id issue

build stage:
./gradlew assembleDebug

firebase stage:
./gradlew appDistributionUploadDebug

In the following scenarios, we will NOT experience the Missing App id issue. Noticed that assembleDebug is called again in firebase stage.

build stage:
./gradlew assembleDebug

firebase stage:
./gradlew assembleDebug appDistributionUploadDebug

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happening the same issue via https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher. I thinks this is some firebase issue only if same is happening with multiple libs